# TitleAreaDialog - Changing the font for setTitle("abc")

Tags: java, fonts, swt, jface, titleareadialog

I am extending TitleAreaDialog in my class.

The default font for the title in the title area does not look very nice.
Is it possible to change the font for the title?
I don't need to change the font any where else in the code, just the title text.

I have tried using FontRegistry, as well as StyledText.

But I can not figure out how to assign the new font to setTitle().

```
FontRegistry fontRegistry = JFaceResources.getFontRegistry();
FontData mainFont = new FontData("Garamond", 18, SWT.NORMAL);
fontRegistry.put("mainFont", new FontData[]{mainFont});
?.setText("Title Text");
?.setFont(fontRegistry.get("mainFont"));  
setTitle(?);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think that's possible. The `title` `String` you set via `setTitle(String)` is displayed in the `private` field `titleLabel`. You cannot access this `Label` when you subclass `TitleAreaDialog`. Consequently, you cannot apply a `Font` to it.

---

So the only possibility I could think of is to create your own `MyTitleAreaDialog extends TrayDialog` based on the code of the original `TitleAreaDialog` and set you `Font` there. You can find the source in your SWT.jar or online.

Comment: Are you suggesting that instead of extending TitleAreaDialog, I should extend TrayDialog. Then create my own title area?

Comment: @jkteater If you really want to change the font, you will have to get your hands dirty. You would have to copy the code from the original TitleAreaDialog and just modify the font of the label within. I would suggest that you overthink this and maybe decide to stick with the default font.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to an old question but it may help someone. You can do it by changing the font in the JFaceResources font registry.

```
static 
{
    JFaceResources.getFontRegistry().put(JFaceResources.BANNER_FONT, yourFont.getFontData());
};
```

I've added this code inside a static block so it only executes once.